# Passing the position of drag and drop element to Django views.py

Tags: javascript, html, django

I've created 2 drag and drop boxes which an icon can be moved between them using the javascript:

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
 ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
 ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id)
}

function drop(ev) {
 ev.preventDefault();
 var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
 ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementID(data));
```

and the relevant html

```
<form action="" method="get">
 <div id="yes_box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"> 
  <img src="/icon/" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" />
  <input type="hidden" name="icon_pos" id="icon_pos" />
 </div> 

 <div id="no_box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
 </div>
 <input type="sumbit" text="submit">
</form>
```

When the user hits the submit button I would like to pass to Django views.py the position of the icon using something like `pos = request.GET('icon_pos')`. What do I need at add to my javascript to update the value of 'icon_pos'?

I've seen similar examples online but since I'm very new to javascript I'm not sure how to adapt these to my situation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Put hidden fields in form for positions you want, then in JS upon drag over take the co-ordinates and put those values in hidden fields inside your form. Now, when you submit the form those values are submitted as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is make use of a variable that can be referenced upon form submission:

```
var pos = 'yes_box'; // Assuming it starts there
```

Then on drop, you would update the target:

```
function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    pos = ev.target.id; // 'pos' becomes the ID of the DIV
}
```

Then you can just pass `pos` through to Django :)

Also, you copied the example wrong:

```
ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.targer.id)
```

Should be:

```
ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id)
```

Hope this helps!